# Website Migrated and updates and plugins can’t be installed

Tags: wordpress

I migrated to a VPS from a shared hosting and now I can’t update any plugin and install anymore.

I tried to delete a plugin and install again but I receive the same issue:

update failed -1 and maintenance mode

I already tried to modify the persmissions in vps and reinstall wordpress